# EntityKey class and $id automatically appear on serialization

Tags: c#, entity-framework, serialization

I recently moved my edmx model to another project. Now, whenever I get any items from the DB via the new project, I constantly receive an $id field and an EntityKey class along with the actual tupple's data, as follows:

`userDetails: {
          $id: '1',
          UserName: 'Shir',
          UserTypeID: 17,
          UserCompany: null,
          EntityKey: {
            $id: '2',
            EntitySetName: 'vw_WebSiteUsers',
            EntityContainerName: 'Name',
            EntityKeyValues: [
              {
                Key: 'ID',
                Value: 113
              },
              {
                Key: 'UserID',
                Value: 29
              }
            ]
          }
        },`

Whenever I try to send one of those entities back, the $id field (that usually contains 1) is read as the true ID value instead of the actual index I use, which has another name (for instance PersonID).

Before I made this change, when the edmx file was in the same project as the API, I had no trouble using EntityFramework at all, but I can't pinpoint the exact definition that's wrong with the new one.

I'm using EntityFramework 6.1.3 on both projects. I've added the next parameter on the old project's WebAPIConfig.cs:

```
config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/html"));
var json = config.Formatters.JsonFormatter;
json.SerializerSettings.PreserveReferencesHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.PreserveReferencesHandling.None;
config.MessageHandlers.Add(new WrappingHandler());
```

I made sure all NuGet versions match for both projects. I've tried fiddling with the new project's Model.Designer.cs file by changing all EntityKey properties from True to False, but that resulted in major errors.

I have many entities and functions in my project already, so a customized class for each entity won't be a sustainable solution for me.

An example of a simple Get call from the old project:

```
vw_WebSiteUsers entity = context.vw_WebSiteUsers.Where(user => user.id== id).FirstOrDefault();
```

Packages.config for the new project:

```
<package id="EFDataSources" version="1.0.0.0" targetFramework="net462" />
  <package id="EntityFramework" version="6.1.3" targetFramework="net462" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Cors" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net462" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net462" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net462" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net462" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net462" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure" version="1.0.0.0" targetFramework="net462" />
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="6.0.4" targetFramework="net462" />
```

Packages.config for the old project:

```
<package id="Antlr" version="3.4.1.9004" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="bootstrap" version="3.0.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="EFDataSources" version="1.0.0.0" targetFramework="net462" />
  <package id="EntityFramework" version="6.1.3" targetFramework="net462" />
  <package id="jQuery" version="1.10.2" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="jQuery.Validation" version="1.11.1" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="log4net" version="2.0.8" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Cors" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Razor" version="3.2.3" targetFramework="net452" />
```

Comment: Entity framework is an ORM. It doesn't perform JSON serialization. Where's your class and serialization code? What did you try to serialize?

Comment: I use Newtonsoft.json, so I don't have a serialization code other than the few lines I posted above. I've read that the $id is a serialization-related problem, and performed the offered solution, but it had no affect.

Comment: the lines you posted don't generate JSON, they only configure the serializer. The string you posted was generated by *something*. Where is that code? You're asking people to guess. EF has nothing to do with JSON. This means that there's very little relevant information in the question